# Path problem in JSP with getRequestDispatcher

Tags: java, jsp

In my application, I am using `jsp:include` as:

```
<jsp:include page="/jsp/selectRoom/listRoom.jsp" />
```

That's working fine, but when I include the same JSP in my servlet as:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("//jsp//selectRoom//listRoom.jsp");
rd.include(request, response);
```

That's not working.
Am I making some syntactical mistake?

---

As log details are not required, i am removing the log details from my post.

Comment: What does appserver logs say?

Comment: How exactly is it "not working" ?

Comment: there is nothing specific in log regarding this. It's just not including the jsp.

Comment: Does it work now that you edited the bracket back in?

Comment: Once again, what does appserver logs say? If you actually don't know where to find it, then say so instead of ignoring helpful hints. Help us help you.

Comment: i already told u, that there is nothing specific in log regarding this. :(, i don't know what the real probz is, i have to complete this by the EOD.

Comment: EOD passed.. did you solve it eventually?

Answer (score 2):

There's a paranthesis missing:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("//jsp//selectRoom//listRoom.jsp");
```

And I'm not quite sure if you really need those double slashes.

Best wishes,
Fabian

Comment: even RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/selectRoom/listRoom.jsp") ; is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with my predecessors. There is no need to escape the / characters with another / in the path. Java String does not interpret the '/' in any special way. It's only '\' that need to be escaped with an additional '\'.

Comment: Yes, but you aren't answering at all. You're only confirming. Just use comments for this.

Answer (score 0):

(Provided you use tomcat) - How about going to your `/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/yourwebapp/org/.../jsp/selectedRoom/yourjsp_jsp.java` and copy-paste the `RequestDispatcher` code from there (you will have to search a little). It should work.

That .java file is the servlet that tomcat has generated from your jsp.

The jsp in question is the one where you successfully use `<jsp:include>`

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that's not working. I did a simple webapp with the following code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class Test extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/selectRoom/listRoom.jsp") ;
        rd.include(request, response) ;
    }
}
```

and that work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/NewPurchase.do");
        rd.forward(request, response) ;
```

Comment: What exactly is the point of this code, if I may ask? It looks the same as the code in the question, but using a different url.